# Is "Hai fatto cosa?" understood as a request to repeat what done?

Tags: meaning

If I were to tell somebody what I did, and the other person asked me *Hai fatto cosa?* I would take it as a request to repeat what I did, similarly to *Cosa hai fatto?* but with *cosa* moved to the end of the sentence for emphasis.

Does the sentence have also another meaning, or am I understanding it wrongly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally, you say *Cosa hai fatto?* to ask other people what they did, also with an interrogative tone of voice.

*Hai fatto cosa?* is not used this way, but usually when the other person didn't correctly understand what you just did, or that person understood that, but he is startled.

> **[A]** Sai che ho fatto? Ho gettato nell'immondizia la tua collezione di fumetti rari a cui tenevi tanto!
>   **[B]** Hai fatto cosa?

In this case you would say *Hai fatto cosa?* with a very angered tone.

Comment: In the example you made, does _Hai fatto cosa?_ have the same meaning of _Cosa?_

Comment: Yes, the tone of your voice would express your astonishment or your anger.